# A custom function structure for my customView.onclick

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I have searched but could not find answer of my question.

This is what I have:

```
private class BoxView extends View {
  private String caption;
  private OnClickListener bvClickListener = null
  public BoxView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.bvClickListener = new this.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick (View v){
    /*v.setCaption("X"); view don't have this method */
      }}
  }

  public void setCaption(String s){
this.caption=s;
invalidate();
  } 
}
```

This is what I want to have:

```
private class BoxView extends View {
  private String caption;
  private OnClickListener bvClickListener = null
  public BoxView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.bvClickListener = new this.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick (BoxView bv){
    bv.setCaption("X");
      }}
  }

  public void setCaption(String s){
this.caption=s;
invalidate();
  } 
}
```

I may need custom methods for my custom views. And I want to be able to pass my custom view instead of view version of it when onclick is triggered so I can access to it directly.

**Updated**

And I want to have access to real object not a converted one. So I want to avoid this:

```
public void onClick (View v){
 ((BoxView)v).setCaption("X");  
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to click listener inside the class where you extends the view.You can set the click listener from activity where you use that particular view. Instead of using Click listener you can implement on touch listener.

Comment: @Rohit Heera ?! You mean we have to use setOnclickListener from activity to set onClickListener cause we can't have OnClickListener in custom view? Well I should say that we can. My question is how to make the parameter `View v` to `BoxView bv` in OnClick

Answer (score 1):

Call `setCaption` method as in `onClick` :

```
public void onClick (View v){
     ((BoxView)v).setCaption("X");  
 }
```

Comment: OK man thanks for the answer but I want to have my whole version of customView not the converted one. Like I want to access to full custom methods and also properties.

Comment: @imsiso: But we can also access all methods and properties using `((BoxView)v)`

Comment: Ok thank you but still I'm looking for a way to be able to access to original type. +1

Comment: I want to know if there is other way like overriding a method so I can make the parameter `View v` to `BoxView bv` in OnClick

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

class Main extents Activity
{
 BoxView boxView;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // if view is used using layout then
boxView = (BoxView)findViewByID(id);

//else if directly used

 boxView = new BoxView(this);

 box.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
 {

 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
       boxView.setCaption("X");
boxView.invalidate();
        }
 });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But I think your solution is not optimized. Like I have layout which will create a grid.and I can't save them in identifiers like that. And also in my approach I want the layout and its view contain their simple behaviors and animations and events in it so it act like a widget and be ready to use. And in activity I just create an object of that layout and give the parameters and the rest will happen in custom layout class